# enlarge image on click and show them in new page

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, html5-canvas

I have created a database with all the images's paths stored inside of it. I can now retrieve them and have them displayed in thumbnails. What i want now is to click on them and get redirected to a new php page where i have the image enlarged. I need this in order then to make annotations to the image and store the annotations in the database. Do you reckon i should place the image in a Canvas ? could you suggest how to proceed ? any help would be much appreciated.

```js
<?php
  
require('db.php');

if (isset($_POST['mostra'])) {
    
    $batch_number = stripslashes($_REQUEST['batch_number']);
    $batch_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $batch_number);
    $product_name = stripslashes($_REQUEST['product_name']);
    $product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $product_name);
    $vial_size = stripslashes($_REQUEST['vial_size']);
    $vial_size = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $vial_size);
    $Sterile = $_POST['Sterile'];
    $Macchina = $_POST['Macchina'];
    
    $select = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT vial_image FROM info_flaconi WHERE batch_number = '$batch_number' AND Macchina = '$Macchina' OR product_name = '$product_name' OR vial_size = '$vial_size' OR Sterile_Area = '$Sterile'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($select)) {
        
            while($row=$select->fetch_assoc()){
                
                
                echo '<tr>
                <td><a href="annotazione.php"><img src="immagini/'.$row['vial_image'].'" style = "width:100px; height:100px; position: relative; top: 70px;"></a></td>
                </tr>';    
               
            }    
        
    }   else{
            echo '<p style="color: white;"> No data available </p>';
        }      
}  

?>


</header>

</body>
           
</html>
```

```html
<?php

include("auth_session.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Import Immagini</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;600;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style_3.css">
 
</head>
<body>
<header>
    
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="biotech.png" alt="">
        </div>
    
    <ul class="nav-area">
    <li><a href="dashboard.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="table/index.html">Contatti</a></li>
    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</a>
</a>
    </ul>   
    <div class = "caricamento">
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            
            <label> carica immagini flaconi: </label>
           

                        
         
            <label> Inserisci numero batch: </label><input type = "text" name= "batch_number" placeholder="batch number">                 
                        
            <label> Inserisci prodotto: </label><input type = "text" name= "product_name" placeholder="product name">
                                             
            <label> Inserisci grandezza flacone: </label><input type = "text" name= "vial_size" placeholder="vial size">
                       
            <input type="submit" name="mostra" value="Mostra flaconi">
            <select name= "Sterile">
                <option value="" >--Select--</option>
                <option value="Sterile Area 1" >Sterile Area 1</option>
                <option value="Sterile Area 2" >Sterile Area 2</option>
                <option value="Sterile Area 3" >Sterile Area 3</option>
                <option value="Sterile Area 4" >Sterile Area 4</option>
                <option value="Sterile Area 5" >Sterile Area 5</option>
                <option value="Sterile Area 6" >Sterile Area 6</option>
                <option value="PDS" >PDS</option>
            </select>
            
            <select name= "Macchina">
                <option value="" >--Select--</option>
                <option value="Sedeneider" >Sedeneider</option>
                <option value="Groheninger" >Groheninger</option>
                <option value="Optrel400" >Optrel400</option>
            </select>      
    </div>            
    </form>
```

Comment: _"Do you reckon i should place the image in a Canvas ?"_ - do you want to do any sort of image _manipulation_? If not, then what advantage would using a canvas have, over simply displaying the image via an `img` element?

Comment: I actually need to make annotations to the image once the image is displayed on the other page

Answer (score 0):

I elaborate a little on what @CBroe commented. At the moment you're retrieving the URLs to the full-size images from your database and generating a html table where each image is rendered at a fixed size of 100x100.

```
echo '<tr> <td > < a href = "annotazione.php" > < img src = "immagini/'.$row['vial_image'].'" style = "width:100px; height:100px; position: relative; top: 70px;" > < /a></td></tr>';
```

As you already have the correct URL, everything you have to do is open this URL inside the current browser window as soon as the user clicks on the thumbnail.
Catching the click event can be done by adding an `onclick="window.open(this.src)"` handler to the `<img>` element. e.g.

```
echo '<tr> <td> <a href = "annotazione.php" > <img onclick="window.open(this.src)" src = "immagini/'.$row['vial_image'].'" style = "width:100px; height:100px; position: relative; top: 70px;"> </a></td></tr>';
```

Comment: This works but it actually opens a new window when I actually want to display the image on the annotation.php where I can draw some sort of a rectangle where the defect of the vial is and then make an annotation to it.